# Django : GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2029

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner Django. I get his 404 error, couldn't find why. Followed all the instructions step by step. Using Django version 3.1.1. Trying to find solution on google, no help.
When I execute `python manage.py runserver` - I get the following message

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 16, 2021 - 06:17:59
Django version 3.1.1, using settings 'lecture3.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /
[16/Nov/2021 06:18:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2029
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 16, 2021 - 06:25:43
Django version 3.1.1, using settings 'lecture3.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /
[16/Nov/2021 06:25:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2029
```

Error on the page is :

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in lecture3.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
hello/
The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

Hello/urls.py

```
 from django.urls import path
    from . import views 
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name="index")
    ]
```

hello/views.py

```
   from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.shortcuts import render

    # Create your views here.
    def index(request):
        return HttpResponse("Hello, world!")
```

lecture3/lecture3/urls.py

```
 from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include
    from django.urls.conf import include

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('hello/', include("hello.urls"))
    ]
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/ -> 404 error
but

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin works fine
http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello works fine
```

Please help, Need your help

When I remove the last line  `path('hello/', include("hello.urls"))` from lecture3/lecture3/urls.py `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` works fine

Comment: You have no path for `/` defined in `urls.py`.

Comment: When I remove the last line `path('hello/', include("hello.urls"))` from lecture3/lecture3/urls.py file, http://127.0.0.1:8000/ works fine

Answer (score -2):

Once the user sends a request for a URL, Django will look into the below-mentioned matches.

1. path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
2. path('hello/', include("hello.urls"))

If u make a request with "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin" or "http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello", it works because Django can find a match for the requested URL.

Since there is no match for "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" in "lecture3/lecture3/urls.py", Django will throw 404.

I believe you are getting a "Hello World" response for "http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/", that is because as soon as django encounters "http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello" it will include "hello.urls". In "hello/urls.py", you have attached "index" view to "", empty URL. Hence view function will be executed.

Comment: Well, when I remove the last line `path('hello/', include("hello.urls"))` from lecture3/lecture3/urls.py file,  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ works fine

Comment: you can modify path('', include("hello.urls") in lecutre3/lecture3/urls.py.  Then django will match the urls from "hello.urls" if URL is like "http://localhost:8080/****'

Comment: I tried it, now http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello is not working

Comment: It won't work, because there is no URL with that pattern. I would suggest you go through the basics of Django again. You can refer to the below channel for Django basics.
https://www.youtube.com/user/thenewboston